# Set the value of second row to NULL MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very strange problem that I am not able to solve at the moment. 
I have two tables. One table contains the IDs and the other table contains transactions.

Let's say IDs are like:

```
1
2
2
3
4
5
6
6
```

and they are joined using the IDs. So what I want to do is if a transaction is there is the transaction table it should be recorded once for each id.

For Example if there is a transaction for **ID = 6**:

```
6 23
6 23
```

**23** is the transaction amount.

It should be shown as:

```
6 23
6 NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want the value once even when the `id`s are duplicated.  If so, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t1.id,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by t1.id order by t1.id) = 1
             then t.amount
        end)
from table1 t1 left join
     transactions t
     on t1.id = t.id;
```

Comment: Yes, it was pretty much like that. Let's talk about another case when there are actually two transactions for one ID. It will make the one transaction null. How to capture that change as well?

Comment: @Uzair . . . Please ask a *new* question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: I have asked a new question. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62146819/set-values-of-some-rows-to-null-mysql